# Does "Asbestos sandwich" have nuances of bad health?

Tags: meaning

In "Clive James in Japan", part 2, which was created in 1986, James says during a bullet train ride that he doesn't know whether he's buying smoked ham or a pair of tights, but that it can't taste worse than a classic British Rail asbestos sandwich.

Does "Asbestos sandwich" have nuances of something being bad for your health (as we now know asbestos can cause mesothelioma), as opposed to it tasting bad and possibly being un-nutritious?

Comment: I doubt the health implications of asbestos were in Clive James's mind when he wrote that. He was just choosing an equally "unappetising" substance to use metaphorically, thinking the standard ***cardboard** sandwich* might sound a bit clichéed (and from a distance, or in the mouth, who could tell the difference between a sheet of cardboard and a sheet of asbestos?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

British Rail's on-board catering became a national joke in the 1970s for its abysmal quality and taste.

Clive James is just playing a variation of this joke.  Yes, he is saying that even if he ate a pair of tights, it would be better than eating on British Rail.  He is making reference to both health and flavour.

I should probably add that things are much better now.

Comment: Also, the salient properties of asbestos are going to be that it is a) poisonous and b) resistant to chemical change. So he's alluding to the idea that BR sandwiches are both indigestible and nauseating.

Answer (score 2):

It really seems that [British Rail sandwiches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Rail_sandwich) had a very bad reputation:

> In British humour, the phrase British Rail sandwich refers to sandwiches sold for consumption on passenger trains of the former British Rail (BR). Its use principally arose in British popular culture through comedic references to the food item as emblematic *of the unappetising fare available aboard Great Britain's railway service during the period of nationalisation from 1948 to 1994.*
>
> According to former BR caterer Myrna Tuddenham, *the poor reputation of BR sandwiches likely owed to the practice of keeping the sandwiches "under glass domes on the counters in refreshment rooms until the corners turned up"*.
>
> Despite the many jokes at its expense, British Rail documents show that in 1993, its last full year as a public company, eight million sandwiches were sold.
>
> Historian Keith Lovegrove wrote that it was "a sandwich of contradictions; it could be cold and soggy, or stale and hard, and the corners of the isosceles triangle-shaped bread would often curl up like the pages of a well-thumbed paperback".

[Asbestos sandwich panels](http://www.sandwich-panels.eu/AMIANTO/ASBESTOS-REMOVAL-sandwich-panels.php): his reference to asbestos is a joke to hint at the 'poisonous' taste of the BR sandwiches.

Comment: The humour couldn't do much to reduce sales of about the only thing available to eat on many trains, and the only thing in that price bracket on many others. The ubiquity of the joke was due to so many people having eaten them despite how unappetising they were.